# iteraing and comparing values in txt file python

Tags: python, loops, io, comparison, iteration

I have multiple files in a folder containing two columns of information: wavenumber and intensity:

```
500.21506 0.01093
500.45613 0.02135
500.69720 0.01043
500.93826 0.01997
501.17933 0.01335
501.42040 0.01579
501.66147 0.01749
501.90253 0.01256
502.14360 0.02054
502.38467 0.01011
502.62574 0.02108
502.86680 0.01132
503.10787 0.01854
```

I need my code to read through each file line by line, and if the wavenumber is between the pre-set lowwavenumber and highwavenumber, write the intensity associated with those wavenumbers. Right now I have this:

```
with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
    for line in g:
        parts = map(float, line.split())
        if parts[0] >= lowwav and parts[0] <= highwav:
            f.write(parts[1])
            f.write('\n')
        else: break
```

and when I command print `parts[0]`(wavenumber in txt file) or print `parts[1]` (intensity in txt file) it prints only the first wavenumber and first intensity in the last file of the folder.

I am new to python and thoroughly confused about how to do this, but it seems logically simple.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any text file. You could read more about reading in data [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
import glob
x = []
for filename in glob.iglob('/Path_to_File/*.txt'):
     x.append(filename)

wave_list = []
for i in x:  
    with open (i,"rU") as infile:
        lines = infile.read().split('\t')            
        for row in lines:
            if row[0] < High_wave and row[0] > Low_wave:
                wave_list.append(row[1])
```

Comment: I got the error message "  File "readinfo1.py", line 60, in <module>
    with open(i,"rU") as infile:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found"

Comment: Try this: "with open (i,"r") as infile:" so just replace "rU" with "r".

Comment: still getting same error message. does the file need to be read in as a string?

Comment: How is your data separated is it Tab separated? If so try the new code as is

Comment: it is separated by a space so I used (' ') rather than \t but still getting same error message